# CakePHP unknown exception thrown

Tags: cakephp, exception, cakephp-2.1

After successfully testing my app locally, I've pushed it to the remote server for further testing. But there, on each and every page, I get the following fatal error: `Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0`. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: could this be a chained exception? exceptions triggered by another previous one? do the error logs say anything more? either cake or php/apache ones?

Comment: you have the right php version there? higher than the required minimum for cake2.x?

Comment: Ah, you can be right, I have only 5.2.17 on my remote. Will talk to the hosting company for an upgrade, thanks for pointing me this obvious issue!

Comment: PHP 5.2.8 < 5.2.17 by the way. so you're good actually

Comment: Oh, I thought I need at least 5.3. Well then, what else shall I look for?

Comment: the usual. cleared cache, all reqired modules, etc. I still think the php internal error logs must have some more info about the issue. also try it in debug mode (2) and see if there is more to find out about it.

Comment: Debug mode was already on. Turned of caches from `core.php`. Checked `error_log` in the hosting's web root folder and nothing new for 2 weeks. Checked also the apache log, nothing there. I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: It looks like there was a problem with the `.htaccess` files, one that wasn't specified in the framework's migration guide. I've updated those at it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

if there was error with the code then there must have been an entry in apache's log. Also, with debug level set, it would definately have given errors unless you have defined your own custom exception handlers. so after all could it be whitespaces ?

**It is not mandatory to have closing php tags in php pages unless you have other scripts below.** I once struggled with it for days. If it is occuring in every page, you can check it once on the default layout, you could also test by commenting every includes in default layout to see if the problem is caused in some other script common to the application.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed that some `.htaccess` files caused the problem. Check my comments above for more details. Thanks for your help!